# Question about type hinting in Python 3.9+

Tags: type-hinting, python-3.9

I have a method that takes a callback function as an argument.

I want to specify a type hint for the callback function signature.

The problem is the signature of the callback function is:

```
def callback_function(event, token, *args)
```

where

```
type(event) = EventClass
type(token) = str
type(args) = tuple  # of str
```

I could write this as:

`callable[[...], returntype]`

but I would like to tighten the type checking to be something useful, at least to making sure `event` and `token` are specified correctly.

Suggestions, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python typing signature (typing.Callable) for function with kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57837609/python-typing-signature-typing-callable-for-function-with-kwargs)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Protocol for this matter, as [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57840786/4061802).

For your specific case it will look like this:

```py
from typing import Protocol, TypeAlias

returntype: TypeAlias = int

class MyCallable(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, event: EventClass, token: str, *args: str) -> returntype: ...


def some_function(callback: MyCallable): ...
```